# How to display a union of three separate columns from the same table side by side with proper column headers

Tags: sql, format, union, rows

I have a complicated SQL query that is returning the correct values, but in the wrong format. My code below looks at three separate columns from the same table, checks if they are null, and then links them together. The problem is that they are all falling under a single column titled after the first column that I checked, which was column 'A'.  I was wondering how I might fix this formatting issue. It's basically SQL transposing a column to a row kinda-sorta.

I did some experimentation to actually get the right values and have confirmed that is working properly. My only issue is formatting my SQL properly.

```
SELECT `A` FROM sensor, login_users, relation 
WHERE (login_users.id = relation.owner_id 
AND relation.dev_id = sensor.Device_ID) 
AND `A` IS NOT NULL

UNION 

SELECT `B` FROM sensor, login_users, relation 
WHERE (login_users.id = relation.owner_id 
AND relation.dev_id = sensor.Device_ID) 
AND `B` IS NOT NULL 

UNION 

SELECT `C` FROM sensor, login_users, relation 
WHERE (login_users.id = relation.owner_id 
AND relation.dev_id = sensor.Device_ID) 
AND `C` IS NOT NULL
```

This is what the  SQL query  is returning

```
A <-- column name
--------------  
2.54  <--  A value
15.00 <--  B value
3.45  <--  C value
```

```
This is what I need it to return.

A        B        C
----     -----    -----
2.54     15.00    3.45
```

Any awesome SQL folk able to offer any assistance on this formatting issue? I'm generally pretty sound with SQL but this one has stumped me.

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Each separate query can return mutiple rows. What happens in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you just need to pivot. I'm making a lot of assumptions here as there is no dbms or data set listed.

```
with dat
as(
SELECT `A` as col, 'a' as spot FROM sensor, login_users, relation 
WHERE (login_users.id = relation.owner_id 
AND relation.dev_id = sensor.Device_ID) 
AND `A` IS NOT NULL

UNION 

SELECT `B` as col, 'b' as spot FROM sensor, login_users, relation 
WHERE (login_users.id = relation.owner_id 
AND relation.dev_id = sensor.Device_ID) 
AND `B` IS NOT NULL 

UNION 

SELECT `C` as col,'c' as spot FROM sensor, login_users, relation 
WHERE (login_users.id = relation.owner_id 
AND relation.dev_id = sensor.Device_ID) 
AND `C` IS NOT NULL
)
select
    case when col = 'a' then `A` end as A
    case when col = 'b' then `B` end as B
    case when col = 'c' then `C` end as C
from
    dat
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to only want one row.  If so, then aggregation does what you want:

```
SELECT MAX(A), MAX(B), MAX(C)
FROM relation r JOIN
     sensor s
     ON r.dev_id = s.Device_ID JOIN
     login_users lu
     ON lu.id = r.owner_id ;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: In this case, I need to be able to grab multiple rows. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Caladin00 . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with more appropriate sample data and desired results.  Also tag your question with the database you are using.